# Getting an error while adding a integer to array object at index (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

while adding a integer to object at index of an array, I am getting an error of "arithmetic on pointer to interface id which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform", didn't know how to resolve it.
Please help.

my code is -

```
 if (arrayTotalAmount.count>0) {
                     int sum = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i<=arrayTotalAmount.count; i++) {
                     sum = (sum+[arrayTotalAmount objectAtIndex:i]);

    }
```

In 4th line I am getting that error.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Objective C array only accepts `NSObject` type. That means it is impossible to insert a primitive value into an `NSArray`. You are getting an error because `objectAtIndex` method returns a pointer which points to that `NSObject`, the arithmetic operations are still valid on pointers but the thing is that the size of a pointer as integer (32bit, 64bit) may differ on device. So one of the solution is typecasting the pointer `sum+(int)[arrayTotalAmount objectAtIndex:i]` which makes no sense in your case.

The solution you are looking for is probably `sum+[[arrayTotalAmount objectAtIndex:i] intValue]` or similar. Assuming that array contains `NSNumber` objects. If the object inside an array is not an `NSNumber` then your app will fail in runtime showing an error indicating that an object `X` does not have a method called `intValue` in which case you will need to figure how to convert object `X` to your `int`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. I found my answer :)

Comment: @Harsh It is the same solution as the other answer. But just since you are working with arrays in Objective-C note that instead of `objectAtIndex:i` you can use `[arrayTotalAmount[i] intValue]`. But in your case it is better to just turn the loop around and use `for(NSNumber *number in arrayTotalAmount) sum += [number intValue];`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert your array object to integer and then add it will work for you.

```
if (arrayTotalAmount.count>0) {
                     int sum = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i<=arrayTotalAmount.count; i++) {
                     sum = (sum+[[arrayTotalAmount objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);

    }
```